# highlighting input value in 2 similar sets of html table cells with jquery

Tags: html, jquery

1. there are two sets of html tables namely 1. Normal Fixation 2. Option Fixation.  Each heading having a pair of similar column data.
2. I need to follow two criteria
3. In the first case i.e. Normal Fixation, when user inputs any value from Normal Fixation table first column values in the Current Basic (textbox id is cb), first two cell values including search value to  be highlighted and the next max value to be highlighted in the second column value.
4. In the second case i.e. Option Fixation, input value to be searched in the option Fixation table first column upto 3 levels and be highlighted and the 4th max value in the second column to be highlighted.

for example : Choose Current level Option as Level 7, Promotion level option as Level 10.  Place the input value in Current Basic as 46200, then 46200, 47600 to be highlighted in the Normal Fixation first column and 56100 to be highlighted in the second column.

Similarly, in the option fixation first column three values i.e. 46200, 47600 and 49000 to be highlighted. the forth max value i.e.56100 to be highlighted in the second column.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Option Payfixation Reference Tool</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" 
            content= "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            
        <meta name="description" content="Normal Payfixation Calculation Tool (for Level 7 and 10 to 13)">
            
        <style> 
           .highlight
        {
        color:red;
        background-color:yellow;
        font-weight:bold;
        }
        
        .highlight2 {
          color: white;
          background-color:green;
          font-weight: bold;
        }
        
        .highlight3 {
          color: green;
          background-color:yellow;
          font-weight: bold;
        }
        
        #nb {display:none;
        }
        
        #dupnb {display:none;
        }
        
        
        </style>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <br><br><br>
     
    <div class="container">
     <center><h2>OPTION PAY FIXATION <br>(A REFERENCE TOOL)</h2></center>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-6">
                
                <div class="table-responsive-md">
                    <table class="table"  border="0">
                    
                        <tr>
                            <td width="250px">Date of Promotion</td><td width="250px"><input class="form-control" type="date" name="dop" id="dop" autocomplete="off" /></td>
                            
                        </tr>
                        
                        
                        <tr>
                            <td>DNI</td><td><select class="form-control" name="dni" id="dni" autocomplete="off">
                                <option value="0">Select</option>
                                <option value="1">01st January</option>
                                <option value="2">01st July</option>
                            </select></td>
                            
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Current Level</td>
                            <td>
                                <select class="form-control" name="cl" id="cl" autocomplete="off">
                                    <option value="0" data-id="">Select</option>
                                    <option value="1" data-id="le7a">Level 7 (GP 4600/-)</option>
                                    <option value="2" data-id="le10a">Level 10 (GP 5400/-)</option>
                                    <option value="3" data-id="le11a">Level 11 (GP 6600/-)</option>
                                    <option value="4" data-id="le12a">Level 12 (GP 7600/-)</option>
                                    <option value="5" data-id="le13a">Level 13 (GP 8700/-)</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>                
                        <tr>
                            <td>Promotion in Level</td>
                            <td>
                                <select class="form-control" name="pl" id="pl" autocomplete="off">
                                    <option value="0" data-id="">Select</option>
                                    <option value="1" data-id = "le10b">Level 10 (GP 5400/-)</option>
                                    <option value="2" data-id = "le11b">Level 11 (GP 6600/-)</option>
                                    <option value="3" data-id = "le12b">Level 12 (GP 7600/-)</option>
                                    <option value="4" data-id = "le13b">Level 13 (GP 8700/-)</option>
                                    <option value="5" data-id = "le13ab">Level 13A (GP 8900/-)</option>                        
                                </select>
                            </td>                    
                        </tr>                
                        <tr>
                            <td>Current Basic</td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="cb" id="cb"  autocomplete="off"/>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="dupcb" id="dupcb"  autocomplete="off"/>
                            </td>                    
                        </tr>                
                        <tr>
                            <td>After one increment<br>(in Current Pay Level)</td>
                            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="aftinc" id="aftinc"  autocomplete="off" readonly/>
                            </td>                    
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                            <td>After TWO increments<br>(in Current Pay Level)</td>
                            <td>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="dupaftinc" id="dupaftinc"  autocomplete="off" readonly/>
                            </td>                    
                        </tr>
                        
                        </table>
                   </div>
                </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
            <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">Normal Fixation</td>
                    <td colspan="1" style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center;"></td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">Option Fixation</td>
                <tr>
            
                <tr>
                    <th>Current Pay Level</th>
                    <th>Promotion Pay Level</th>
                    <th>Pay from <input type="text" id="pf" style="width:100px; border:0; font-weight:bold; color:red;" readonly/></th>
                    
                    <!--OPTION FIXATION HEADINGS-->
                     <th>Current Pay Level</th>
                    <th>Promotion Pay Level</th>
                    <th>Pay from <input type="text" id="pf" style="width:100px; border:0; font-weight:bold; color:red;" readonly/></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="CPLholder">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="PPLholder">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="nb" id="nb" autocomplete="off" readonly/></td>
                    
                    <!--OPTION FIXATION CONTENT-->
                    <td id="CPLholder2">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="PPLholder2">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="dupnb" id="dupnb" autocomplete="off" readonly/></td>
                </tr>
                
                
                
                
            </table>   
            </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>      
        </div>  
    </div>
    
    
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#dni').on('click', function() {
        $('#pf').val($('#dop').val());
            
            if ( this.value == '1')
            {
            var revDate = new Date($("#dop").val());
            var plusOneYear = new Date(revDate.setFullYear(revDate.getFullYear() + 1, revDate.getMonth() - 8));
          var revisedate = (new Date(plusOneYear)).toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
          
          document.querySelector("#nid").value = revisedate;
          
          }
          else if ( this.value == '2')
          {
            var revDate = new Date($("#dop").val());
            var plusOneYear = new Date(revDate.setFullYear(revDate.getFullYear() + 1, revDate.getMonth() - 2));
          var revisedate = (new Date(plusOneYear)).toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
          document.querySelector("#nid").value = revisedate;
          }
        });
    });
    </script>
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#cb').keyup(function(e) {
            var txtVal = $(this).val();
            $('#dupcb').val(txtVal);
        });
    });
    
    </script>
    
    
    
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
    
            var cplData = {
                'le7a' : [44900,46200,47600,49000,50500,52000,53600,55200,56900,58600,60400,62200,64100,66000,68000,70000,72100,74300, 76500,78800,81200,83600,86100,88700,91400,94100,96900,99800],
                'le10a' : [56100,57800,59500,61300,63100,65000,67000,69000,71100,73200,75400,77700, 80000, 82400, 84900, 87400, 90000, 92700, 95500, 98400, 101400, 104400, 107500, 110700, 114000, 117400, 120900, 124500],
                'le11a' : [67700,69700,71800,74000,76200,78500,80900,83300,85800,88400,91100,93800, 96600, 99500,102500, 105600, 108800, 112100, 115500, 119000, 122600, 126300, 130100, 134000, 138000, 142100, 146400, 150800, 155300],
                'le12a' : [78800,81200,83600,86100,88700,91400,94100,96900,99800,102800,105900,109100, 112400, 115800, 119300, 122900, 126600, 130400, 134300, 138300, 142400, 146700, 151100, 155600, 160300, 165100, 170100, 175200, 180500],
                'le13a' : [123100,123800,130600,134500,138500,142700,147000,151400,155900,160600,165400,170400, 175500, 180800, 186200, 191800, 197600, 203500, 209600, 215900]
            }
    
            var pplData = {
                'le10b' : [56100,57800,59500,61300,63100,65000,67000,69000,71100,73200,75400,77700, 80000, 82400, 84900, 87400, 90000, 92700, 95500, 98400, 101400, 104400, 107500, 110700, 114000, 117400, 120900, 124500],
                'le11b' : [67700,69700,71800,74000,76200,78500,80900,83300,85800,88400,91100,93800, 96600, 99500,102500, 105600, 108800, 112100, 115500, 119000, 122600, 126300, 130100, 134000, 138000, 142100, 146400, 150800, 155300],
                'le12b' : [78800,81200,83600,86100,88700,91400,94100,96900,99800,102800,105900,109100, 112400, 115800, 119300, 122900, 126600, 130400, 134300, 138300, 142400, 146700, 151100, 155600, 160300, 165100, 170100, 175200, 180500],
                'le13b' : [123100,123800,130600,134500,138500,142700,147000,151400,155900,160600,165400,170400, 175500, 180800, 186200, 191800, 197600, 203500, 209600, 215900],
                'le13ab' : [131100,135000,139100,143300,147600,152000,156600,161300,166100,171100,176200,181500]
            }
    
    
            $('#cl').on('change', function() 
            {
                var dataId = $('option:selected', this).data('id');
                $('#cb, #aftinc, #nb').val('');
                $('#CPLholder').find('table tr').removeClass('highlight highlight2');
                $('#PPLholder').find('table tr').removeClass('highlight3');
                if(dataId)
                {
                    $('#CPLholder').html(createTable(dataId,'cpl'));
                }
                else
                {
                   $('#CPLholder').html('');
                }
            });
    
    
            $('#pl').on('change', function() 
            {
                var dataId = $('option:selected', this).data('id');
                $('#cb, #aftinc, #nb').val('');
                $('#CPLholder').find('table tr').removeClass('highlight highlight2');
                $('#PPLholder').find('table tr').removeClass('highlight3');
                if(dataId)
                {
                    $('#PPLholder').html(createTable(dataId,'ppl'));
                }
                else
                {
                   $('#PPLholder').html(''); 
                   $('#PPLholder2').html(''); 
                }
            });
    
    
            function createTable(dataId,plType)
            {
                var table = $('<table id="'+dataId+'" class="table table-responsive">');
                var data = (plType == 'cpl') ? cplData[dataId] : pplData[dataId];
                $.each(data, function(i, item) 
                {
                    table.append('<tr><td>' + item + '</td></tr>');
                });        
                return table;
            }
    <!--for NORMAL FIXATION HIGHLIGHT - starts-->
            $('#cb').on('change keyup', function () 
            {
                var search = $(this).val();
                var activeCPL = $('#'+$('#CPLholder').find('table').attr('id'));
                var pplId = $('#PPLholder').find('table').attr('id');
                var activePPL = $('#'+pplId);
    
                if(activeCPL != undefined) activeCPL.find('tr').removeClass('highlight highlight2');
                $('#aftinc').val('');
                if(activePPL != undefined) activePPL.find('tr').removeClass('highlight3');
    
                var aftinc = 0;
    
                activeCPL.find('tr').find('td').each(function()
                {
                    if($(this).text() == search)
                    {
                        $(this).parent('tr').addClass('highlight');
                        $(this).parent('tr').next().addClass('highlight2');
                        
                        aftinc = $(this).parent('tr').next().text();
                        $('#aftinc').val(aftinc);
                    }
                });
                
                if(aftinc > 0)
                {
                    var closest = pplData[pplId].reduce((prev, curr) => {
                        return Math.abs(curr - aftinc) < Math.abs(prev - aftinc) && (curr - aftinc) > 0 ? curr : prev;
                    });                
                }
    
                if (closest - aftinc > 0) 
                {
                    activePPL.find('tr').find('td').each(function()
                    {
                        if (this.innerHTML == closest) 
                        {
                            $(this).parent('tr').addClass('highlight3');
                            var nb = $(this).parent('tr').text();
                            var nnb = $(this).parent('tr').next().text();
                            $('#nnb').val(nnb);
                            $('#nb').val(nb);
                        }
                    });
                }
    
            });
            
    <!--for NORMAL FIXATION HIGHLIGHT - Ends-->     
            
        });
        </script>
        
        
        
    
        
    <!----> 
        
        
     <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
    
            var cplData = {
                'le7a' : [44900,46200,47600,49000,50500,52000,53600,55200,56900,58600,60400,62200,64100,66000,68000,70000,72100,74300, 76500,78800,81200,83600,86100,88700,91400,94100,96900,99800],
                'le10a' : [56100,57800,59500,61300,63100,65000,67000,69000,71100,73200,75400,77700, 80000, 82400, 84900, 87400, 90000, 92700, 95500, 98400, 101400, 104400, 107500, 110700, 114000, 117400, 120900, 124500],
                'le11a' : [67700,69700,71800,74000,76200,78500,80900,83300,85800,88400,91100,93800, 96600, 99500,102500, 105600, 108800, 112100, 115500, 119000, 122600, 126300, 130100, 134000, 138000, 142100, 146400, 150800, 155300],
                'le12a' : [78800,81200,83600,86100,88700,91400,94100,96900,99800,102800,105900,109100, 112400, 115800, 119300, 122900, 126600, 130400, 134300, 138300, 142400, 146700, 151100, 155600, 160300, 165100, 170100, 175200, 180500],
                'le13a' : [123100,123800,130600,134500,138500,142700,147000,151400,155900,160600,165400,170400, 175500, 180800, 186200, 191800, 197600, 203500, 209600, 215900]
            }
    
            var pplData = {
                'le10b' : [56100,57800,59500,61300,63100,65000,67000,69000,71100,73200,75400,77700, 80000, 82400, 84900, 87400, 90000, 92700, 95500, 98400, 101400, 104400, 107500, 110700, 114000, 117400, 120900, 124500],
                'le11b' : [67700,69700,71800,74000,76200,78500,80900,83300,85800,88400,91100,93800, 96600, 99500,102500, 105600, 108800, 112100, 115500, 119000, 122600, 126300, 130100, 134000, 138000, 142100, 146400, 150800, 155300],
                'le12b' : [78800,81200,83600,86100,88700,91400,94100,96900,99800,102800,105900,109100, 112400, 115800, 119300, 122900, 126600, 130400, 134300, 138300, 142400, 146700, 151100, 155600, 160300, 165100, 170100, 175200, 180500],
                'le13b' : [123100,123800,130600,134500,138500,142700,147000,151400,155900,160600,165400,170400, 175500, 180800, 186200, 191800, 197600, 203500, 209600, 215900],
                'le13ab' : [131100,135000,139100,143300,147600,152000,156600,161300,166100,171100,176200,181500]
            }
    
    
            $('#cl').on('change', function() 
            {
                var dataId = $('option:selected', this).data('id');
                $('#dupcb, #dupaftinc, #dupnb').val('');
                $('#CPLholder2').find('table tr').removeClass('highlight highlight2');
                $('#PPLholder2').find('table tr').removeClass('highlight3');
                if(dataId)
                {
                    $('#CPLholder2').html(createTable(dataId,'cpl'));
                }
                else
                {
                   $('#CPLholder2').html('');
                }
            });
    
    
            $('#pl').on('change', function() 
            {
                var dataId = $('option:selected', this).data('id');
                $('#dupcb, #dupaftinc, #dupnb').val('');
                $('#CPLholder2').find('table tr').removeClass('highlight highlight2');
                $('#PPLholder2').find('table tr').removeClass('highlight3');
                if(dataId)
                {
                    $('#PPLholder2').html(createTable(dataId,'ppl'));
                }
                else
                {
                   $('#PPLholder2').html(''); 
                }
            });
    
    
            function createTable(dataId,plType)
            {
                var table = $('<table id="'+dataId+'" class="table table-responsive">');
                var data = (plType == 'cpl') ? cplData[dataId] : pplData[dataId];
                $.each(data, function(i, item) 
                {
                    table.append('<tr><td>' + item + '</td></tr>');
                });        
                return table;
            }
    <!--for OPTION FIXATION HIGHLIGHT - starts-->
            $('#cb').on('change keyup', function () 
            {
                var search = $(this).val();
                var dupactiveCPL = $('#'+$('#CPLholder2').find('table').attr('id'));
                var duppplId = $('#PPLholder2').find('table').attr('id');
                var dupactivePPL = $('#'+duppplId);
    
                if(dupactiveCPL != undefined) dupactiveCPL.find('tr').removeClass('highlight highlight2');
                $('#dupaftinc').val('');
                if(dupactivePPL != undefined) dupactivePPL.find('tr').removeClass('highlight3');
    
                var dupaftinc = 0;
    
                dupactiveCPL.find('tr').find('td').each(function()
                {
                    
                    if($(this).text() == search)
                    {
                        $(this).parent('tr').addClass('highlight');
                        $(this).parent('tr').next().addClass('highlight2');
                        
                        dupaftinc = $(this).parent('tr').next().next().text();
                        $('#dupaftinc').val(dupaftinc);
                        
                        
                    }
                });
                
                if(aftinc > 0)
                {
                    var closest = pplData[duppplId].reduce((prev, curr) => {
                        return Math.abs(curr - dupaftinc) < Math.abs(prev - dupaftinc) && (curr - aftinc) > 0 ? curr : prev;
                    });                
                }
    
                if (closest - dupaftinc > 0) 
                {
                    dupactivePPL.find('tr').find('td').each(function()
                    {
                        if (this.innerHTML == closest) 
                        {
                            $(this).parent('tr').addClass('highlight3');
                            var nb = $(this).parent('tr').text();
                            var nnb = $(this).parent('tr').next().text();
                            
                            $('#dupnb').val(nnb);
                        }
                    });
                }
    
            });
            
    <!--for OPTION FIXATION HIGHLIGHT - Ends-->     
            
        });
        </script>   
        
        
        
        
        
        
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cl').on('change', function() {
          
            $("#nb").show();
            $("#dupnb").show();
          
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: not able to understand `1st column, two more values,  2nd table column with one immediate higher value to the previous 3rd highlighted value`. Can you explain in simple language. Maybe you can share steps, and expected behaviour with example.

Comment: @SudiptoRoy In the first set of table cells, only 2 values will be checked with respect to the input value and the third value will be highlighted in the 2nd table column.  Its working fine.  Whereas, coming to 2nd set of table columns, the 3 consecutive values to be highlighted from the first column and one value in second column.  For ex.  assume that comparison is between level 7 and level 10.  The input value given as 47600 from the current level 7  to be highlighted in table column 47600, 49000 and 50500 and next immediate higher value would be 56100 in the Level 10 .

Comment: currently your code is not working for comparison between level 7 and level 10, current basic = 55200. Check if I am correct.

Comment: @SudiptoRoy yes, why so. rest all are working fine.  where is the flaw

Comment: You will be able to find that out faster.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but is this what you want the expected behaviour to be?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dni').on('click', function() {
    $('#pf').val($('#dop').val());
    if (this.value == '1') {
      var revDate = new Date($("#dop").val());
      var plusOneYear = new Date(revDate.setFullYear(revDate.getFullYear() + 1, revDate.getMonth() - 8));
      var revisedate = (new Date(plusOneYear)).toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
      document.querySelector("#nid").value = revisedate;
    } else if (this.value == '2') {
      var revDate = new Date($("#dop").val());
      var plusOneYear = new Date(revDate.setFullYear(revDate.getFullYear() + 1, revDate.getMonth() - 2));
      var revisedate = (new Date(plusOneYear)).toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
      document.querySelector("#nid").value = revisedate;
    }
  });
});
$(function() {
  var cplData = {
    'le7a': [44900, 46200, 47600, 49000, 50500, 52000, 53600, 55200, 56900, 58600, 60400, 62200, 64100, 66000, 68000, 70000, 72100, 74300, 76500, 78800, 81200, 83600, 86100, 88700, 91400, 94100, 96900, 99800],
    'le10a': [56100, 57800, 59500, 61300, 63100, 65000, 67000, 69000, 71100, 73200, 75400, 77700, 80000, 82400, 84900, 87400, 90000, 92700, 95500, 98400, 101400, 104400, 107500, 110700, 114000, 117400, 120900, 124500],
    'le11a': [67700, 69700, 71800, 74000, 76200, 78500, 80900, 83300, 85800, 88400, 91100, 93800, 96600, 99500, 102500, 105600, 108800, 112100, 115500, 119000, 122600, 126300, 130100, 134000, 138000, 142100, 146400, 150800, 155300],
    'le12a': [78800, 81200, 83600, 86100, 88700, 91400, 94100, 96900, 99800, 102800, 105900, 109100, 112400, 115800, 119300, 122900, 126600, 130400, 134300, 138300, 142400, 146700, 151100, 155600, 160300, 165100, 170100, 175200, 180500],
    'le13a': [123100, 123800, 130600, 134500, 138500, 142700, 147000, 151400, 155900, 160600, 165400, 170400, 175500, 180800, 186200, 191800, 197600, 203500, 209600, 215900]
  }

  var pplData = {
    'le10b': [56100, 57800, 59500, 61300, 63100, 65000, 67000, 69000, 71100, 73200, 75400, 77700, 80000, 82400, 84900, 87400, 90000, 92700, 95500, 98400, 101400, 104400, 107500, 110700, 114000, 117400, 120900, 124500],
    'le11b': [67700, 69700, 71800, 74000, 76200, 78500, 80900, 83300, 85800, 88400, 91100, 93800, 96600, 99500, 102500, 105600, 108800, 112100, 115500, 119000, 122600, 126300, 130100, 134000, 138000, 142100, 146400, 150800, 155300],
    'le12b': [78800, 81200, 83600, 86100, 88700, 91400, 94100, 96900, 99800, 102800, 105900, 109100, 112400, 115800, 119300, 122900, 126600, 130400, 134300, 138300, 142400, 146700, 151100, 155600, 160300, 165100, 170100, 175200, 180500],
    'le13b': [123100, 123800, 130600, 134500, 138500, 142700, 147000, 151400, 155900, 160600, 165400, 170400, 175500, 180800, 186200, 191800, 197600, 203500, 209600, 215900],
    'le13ab': [131100, 135000, 139100, 143300, 147600, 152000, 156600, 161300, 166100, 171100, 176200, 181500]
  }
  $('#cl').on('change', function() {
    var dataId = $('option:selected', this).data('id');
    $('#cb, #aftinc, #nb').val('');
    $('#CPLholder').find('table tr').removeClass('highlight highlight2');
    $('#PPLholder').find('table tr').removeClass('highlight3');
    if (dataId) {
      $('#CPLholder').html(createTable(dataId, 'cpl'));
      $('#CPLholder2').html(createTable(dataId, 'cpl'));
    } else {
      $('#CPLholder').html('');
      $('#CPLholder2').html('');
    }
  });
  $('#pl').on('change', function() {
    var dataId = $('option:selected', this).data('id');
    $('#cb, #aftinc, #nb').val('');
    $('#CPLholder').find('table tr').removeClass('highlight highlight2');
    $('#PPLholder').find('table tr').removeClass('highlight3');
    if (dataId) {
      $('#PPLholder').html(createTable(dataId, 'ppl'));
      $('#PPLholder2').html(createTable(dataId, 'ppl'));
    } else {
      $('#PPLholder').html('');
      $('#PPLholder2').html('');
    }
  });

  function createTable(dataId, plType) {
    var table = $('<table id="' + dataId + '" class="table table-responsive">');
    var data = (plType == 'cpl') ? cplData[dataId] : pplData[dataId];
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      table.append('<tr><td>' + item + '</td></tr>');
    });
    return table;
  }
  <!--for NORMAL FIXATION HIGHLIGHT - starts-->
  $('#cb').on('change keyup', function() {
    var search = $(this).val();
    var activeCPL = $('#' + $('#CPLholder').find('table').attr('id'));
    var pplId = $('#PPLholder').find('table').attr('id');
    var activePPL = $('#' + pplId);

    if (activeCPL != undefined) activeCPL.find('tr').removeClass('highlight highlight2');
    $('#aftinc').val('');
    if (activePPL != undefined) activePPL.find('tr').removeClass('highlight3');
    var aftinc = 0;
    activeCPL.find('tr').find('td').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() == search) {
        $(this).parent('tr').addClass('highlight');
        $(this).parent('tr').next().addClass('highlight2');
        // ADDED BELOW LINE
        $(this).parent('tr').next().next().addClass('highlight2');
        // ADDED AN EXTRA .next()
        aftinc = $(this).parent('tr').next().next().text();
        $('#aftinc').val(aftinc);
      }
    });
    if (aftinc > 0) {
      var closest = pplData[pplId].reduce((prev, curr) => {
        return Math.abs(curr - aftinc) < Math.abs(prev - aftinc) && (curr - aftinc) > 0 ? curr : prev;
      });
    }
    if (closest - aftinc > 0) {
      activePPL.find('tr').find('td').each(function() {
        if (this.innerHTML == closest) {
          $(this).parent('tr').addClass('highlight3');
          var nb = $(this).parent('tr').text();
          var nnb = $(this).parent('tr').next().text();
          $('#nnb').val(nnb);
          $('#nb').val(nb);
        }
      });
    }
  });
  <!--for NORMAL FIXATION HIGHLIGHT - Ends-->       
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cl').on('change', function() {
    $("#nb").show();
    $("#nnb").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.highlight2 {
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.highlight3 {
  color: green;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#nb {
  display: none;
}

#nnb {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br><br><br>
<div class="container">
  <center>
    <h2>OPTION PAY FIXATION <br>(A REFERENCE TOOL)</h2>
  </center>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="table-responsive-md">
        <table class="table" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="250px">Date of Promotion</td>
            <td width="250px"><input class="form-control" type="date" name="dop" id="dop" autocomplete="off" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>DNI</td>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control" name="dni" id="dni" autocomplete="off">
                <option value="0">Select</option>
                <option value="1">01st January</option>
                <option value="2">01st July</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Current Level</td>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control" name="cl" id="cl" autocomplete="off">
                <option value="0" data-id="">Select</option>
                <option value="1" data-id="le7a">Level 7 (GP 4600/-)</option>
                <option value="2" data-id="le10a">Level 10 (GP 5400/-)</option>
                <option value="3" data-id="le11a">Level 11 (GP 6600/-)</option>
                <option value="4" data-id="le12a">Level 12 (GP 7600/-)</option>
                <option value="5" data-id="le13a">Level 13 (GP 8700/-)</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Promotion in Level</td>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control" name="pl" id="pl" autocomplete="off">
                <option value="0" data-id="">Select</option>
                <option value="1" data-id="le10b">Level 10 (GP 5400/-)</option>
                <option value="2" data-id="le11b">Level 11 (GP 6600/-)</option>
                <option value="3" data-id="le12b">Level 12 (GP 7600/-)</option>
                <option value="4" data-id="le13b">Level 13 (GP 8700/-)</option>
                <option value="5" data-id="le13ab">Level 13A (GP 8900/-)</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Current Basic</td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="cb" id="cb" autocomplete="off" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>After one increment<br>(in Previous scale)</td>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="aftinc" id="aftinc" autocomplete="off" readonly/></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">Normal Fixation</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center;"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">Option Fixation</td>
            <tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Current Pay Level</th>
                <th>Promotion Pay Level</th>
                <th>Pay from <input type="text" id="pf" style="width:100px; border:0; font-weight:bold; color:red;" readonly/></th>
                <!--OPTION FIXATION HEADINGS-->
                <th>Current Pay Level</th>
                <th>Promotion Pay Level</th>
                <th>Pay from <input type="text" id="pf" style="width:100px; border:0; font-weight:bold; color:red;" readonly/></th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id="CPLholder">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="PPLholder">&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="nb" id="nb" autocomplete="off" readonly/></td>
                <!--OPTION FIXATION CONTENT-->
                <td id="CPLholder2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td id="PPLholder2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="nb" id="nb" autocomplete="off" readonly/></td>
              </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the application, two table sets are there by name NORMAL FIXATION and OPTION FIXATION.  In my question, NORMAL FIXATION is working fine with highlighting of 2 level values.  Whereas, whatever your answer now doing is to be happened with OPTION FIXATION set of table.  Both NORMAL and OPTION FIXATION Tables should work simultaneously.

Comment: in your code there is this comment `<!--for NORMAL FIXATION HIGHLIGHT - starts-->`, which means the code works only for normal fixation part. and there is nothing like so for option fixation. For both Normal and Option fixation to work the same way, do the code changes for option fixation accordingly.

Comment: As I explained in my query, Normal fixation and Option fixation are 2 different methods of calculation.  Jquery for calculation of Nor fixation is working fine.  Whereas,  Jquery for option fix is not working.  example : Choose Current level as Level 7, Promotion level as Level 10. if the input val in Current Basic as 46200, then 46200, 47600 to be highlighted - Normal Fixation 1st col and 56100 to be highlighted in the 2nd col. Similarly, in the option fixation 1st col 3 vals i.e. 46200, 47600 & 49000 to be highlighted. the 4th max val i.e.56100 to be highlighted in the 2nd col.